# Domain of a square root natural log function

Tags: calculus

I'm currently trying to determine the domain of this function without having to draw it. The function is as follows:
$$ f(x) = \sqrt {\ln (2 \cos x)}$$

Or, in other words, the square root of $\ln(2\cos x)$ (Apologies if format is incorrect - still learning!)

From what I have learnt thus far, the domain for f(x) in this situation would be where whatever under the square root is not 0. However, I also note that $(2 \cos x)$ cannot be 0.

By setting $(2 \cos x)\ne 0$, I got the domain $[0,\frac\pi2)\cup(3\frac\pi2,\pi]$

However, drawing $f(x)$ in Desmos yields a domain of $[-\frac\pi3, \frac\pi3]$.

Have I gone wrong in setting $(2\cos x) \ne 0$? How else could I go about finding the domain for $f(x)$?

Many thanks in advance! Will be around to answer any follow-up questions.

Comment: What is the range of your function ? Is it mapping real numbers to real numbers ? If so, how will you take the square root of a negative number - what if 2cos(x) is less than 1, for example ?

Comment: We were not given a range for the function - the question asks whether f(x) has a domain of [0, pi) or not

Answer (score 1):

Two conditions:

1. $\ln(2\cos x)$ has to be defined, which means $\cos x>0$.
2. $\ln(2\cos x)\ge 0$, which means $2\cos x\ge 1$.

The second condition implies the first, therefore the domain is defined by
$$\cos x\ge \frac12=\cos \frac\pi3\iff -\frac\pi 3\le x\le\frac\pi 3 \pmod{2\pi}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Can I ask what (mod 2pi) means?

Comment: I'm not sure it's standard in the context of inequalities. Here it just means $$-\frac\pi 3+2k\pi\le x\le\frac\pi 3+2k\pi\enspace\text{for some }\;k\in\mathbf Z. $$